# python find GCD recursively meet error

Tags: python, recursion

I have two pieces of python code finding two positive integers' GCD.

Here is the correct one:

```
def gcdRecur(a, b):

    if b == 0:
        return a
    return gcdRecur(b, a%b)
```

Here is the one with bug:

```
def gcdRecur(a, b):

    a = max(a, b)
    b = min(a, b)
    if b == 0:
        return a
    return gcdRecur(b, a%b)
```

It's easy to see the differences between these two pieces of code. And I know that there is no need to  add

```
 a = max(a, b)
 b = min(a, b)
```

before the control flow. I can't find any logic mistakes in the latter code, but it print out the wrong result.

```
------use former code find GCD of 182 ans 224------
print out 14
------use former code find GCD of 182 ans 224------
print out 224(wrong answer)
```

So I guess it may be associated with the principle of recursion in python which I don't know at all. Can anyone help me and tell me what's going on T T.

Thank you.

Comment: "I can't find any logic mistakes in the latter code" Then you know the error is not in the latter code. What happens when you call gcdRecur(5, 10)? `a` becomes 10, then on the following line, you do `b = max(a, b)` which essentially is `b = max(10, 10)`. Thus, if `b > a`after your two lines, `a` and `b` will __always__ be the same value.

Comment: @VincentSavard  God, I didn't notice it! Thank you very much.

Comment: `a, b = sorted((a, b), reverse=True)`

Comment: Or `b, a = sorted((a, b))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you call `a = max(a,b)` and b is the max value, the old `a` will be missing, and `a` will equal `b` which leads to `gcd(b,b) == b`